# Are 'no interest if paid in in x months' credit cards worth it?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, interest-rate, promotion

My current laptop is dying the slow death, specifically the charging circuit in the motherboard is failing; the battery charges in another laptop of the same model. I've considered just running it on the wire forever, but as I often have to go out to job sites where I'm not guaranteed an available plug, that's not completely possible.

To the point though, I need a new laptop; unfortunately, being something I use for work, I can't really go without one forever. I don't have the resources on hands to buy one outright, and don't have time to save up. My question is, are those "no interest if paid off in x months" legitimate? I know it's always a hazard to rely in future income, but I plan on paying it off well within the prescribed period.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't buy it outright.
You can't take the time to save up.

if the remaining choice is between a card that charges from day one, and a card with this kind of grace period, the grace card is the better choice. Plan wisely, pay it in full before that rate starts to be charged.

One additional note - There are two groups of people, the pay-in-fullers and the balance carriers. I believe that one should pay in full, and never pay interest.

A zero rate offer can be used by the balance carrier to feel great for 12 months, but have even more debt after the rate kicks in.

As a pay-in-full user, I've used the zero rate to throw $20K at the 5.25% mortgage, and planned a refinance to 3.5% just as it ended. a $750 savings (after the tax effect) well worth the bit of effort.

The fees should be in the fine print. My zero rate had a transfer fee, $50 max, which was nothing in comparison to the savings.

Comment: When you put it like that, it makes perfect sense, but I've been taught to question basically any marketing strategy. Do these kinds of cards come with hidden fees or some tricky way to wring extra $$$ out?

Thanks

Comment: @sidney balance transfer fee, most commonly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit joe. I plan on paying well above the minimum (I usually come out with about $300/mo discretionary, so I can have it knocked out in three months as opposed to their twelve)

Comment: @Sidney it's worth noting that the balance transfer fees are typically significantly lower than the amount of interest you avoid paying.  As such bouncing a balance around can help accelerate your pay down a bit.  It's at best only a medium term solution because you'll eventually run out of banks to open new xfer accounts to.

Comment: @Sidney You may have already considered it, but many of those types of cards have a higher interest rate after the grace period, and if you don't pay it off in time, it ALL hits at once for the entire original balance for the past year. To avoid this, plan on paying it off well ahead of time before the grace period expires.

Comment: D&D - Sidney notes that he'll be paid in full long before the zero runs out. But, great advice and warning for a new reader.

Comment: Also, I haven't noticed mention of, be ware of "If you aren't paid in full at end of time, you owe all the interest that would have accrued otherwise." -EDIT NM, Doresoom mentions it as well. @JoeTaxpayer I'm sure everyone intends to pay it off ahead of time...

Comment: @WernerCD - Great point, some offers have such a clause. Not all. In my case, if the mortgage came later and I had no funds to pay the card, I'd have started paying interest, at 24%. Just not retroactive.

Answer (score 5):

It has been reported in consumer media (for example Clark Howard's radio program) that the "no interest for 12 months" contracts *could* trick you with the terms and the dates on the contract.

**Just as an example:**

You borrow $1000 on 12/1/2013, same as cash for 12 months.  The contract will state the due date very clearly as 12/1/2014.  BUT they statements you get will take payment on the 15th of each month.

So you will dutifully pay your statements as they come in, but when you pay the final statement on 12/15/2014, you are actually 14 days late, have violated the terms, and you now owe all the interest that accumulated (and it wasn't a favorable rate).

That doesn't happen all the time.  Not all contracts are written that way.  But you better read your agreement.

### Check for:

- The due date
- The penalty dates
- How you must pay
- Where you must pay
- Are there prepayment penalties?

Some companies use the same as cash deal because they want to move product. Some do it because they want to trick you with financing.  Bottom line is, you better read the contract.

Comment: For this reason it's better to try and pay off the debt before the final month. I had some emergency car repairs and was offered a 6 months no interest deal; I paid it back in 3 months and walked away better off.

Answer (score 5):

I too am a full-monthly-statement-balance payer and I received a balance transfer offer from my credit-card company. This one was quite different from
many others that I have read about on this forum.

I could do a balance transfer for any amount up to $X
from another credit card, or use the enclosed "checks" to pay 
some other (non-credit-card) bills,
and I would not have to pay *any* interest for 12 months on the amount
thus borrowed.  **But,**

- There would be a 2% service charge on the amount I was borrowing. This
  amount would be billed on the next monthly statement, and it would have
  to be paid in full by the due date of that month's payment, that is,
  within the 25-day
  grace period allowed for payment of monthly statements. Else, interest would
  start being charged on the unpaid part of the service charge at the usual
  humongous rate of H% per month.
- If I had not paid the *previous* month's balance in full, I would
  be charged interest at H% per month on the service charge starting from
  Day One; no free ride till the due date of the next month's statement.
  Of course, the balance carried over from last month would also be charged
  interest at H%.
- If I had paid last month's bill in full, but there were any other
  charges (purchases) during the current month, then 
  unless **the entire amount due**, this month's purchases plus service
  charge **and** that "interest-free-for-twelve-months loan" 
  balance was paid off within the 25-day grace period, my purchases would
  be deemed unpaid and would start being charged interest.

In short, the *only* way to avoid paying interest on the amount borrowed
was to start with a card showing a $0 balance due on the previous
month's statement, not make *any* charges on that card for a whole
year, and pay off that 2% service charge within the grace period.
It might also have required that one-twelfth of that interest-free
loan be repaid each month, but 
I had stopped reading the offer at this point and filed it in the round
circular file.

In short, while @JoeTaxpayer's tale of how "As a pay-in-full user,
I've used the zero rate to throw $20K at the 5.25% mortgage" is
undoubtedly how things worked once, it is not at all clear that
they still work that way. At least, they don't work that way for
me.  Heck, once upon a time, for a period of
about 3 months, you could *earn* 1.5% interest per month *from*
the credit card company by *overpaying* your credit card bill
considerably. Their computers then just "added on" 1.5% interest
by multiplying your credit balance -$X by 1.015 and so *you*
got 1.5% per month interest from the credit card company. The credit card
agreements (and the software!) got changed in a hurry, and nowdays
all credit-card agreements state in the fine print that if you
overpay your bill, you don't earn any interest on the overpayment.

Comment: +1 the fine print can be different for any new deal.

Comment: In Australia, when we get offered zero interest periods (whether 6 months or 12 months) on transfers we do not get charged any fees. The only requirements to get the zero interest for the full period is that the minimum monthly payment must be paid by the due date each month and the outstanding amount be fully paid off before the end of the free period. The banks and other credit card providers make these offers because the majority of people don't pay the full amount by the end of the free period so end up paying interest (as Joe says).

Comment: @Victor Banks and credit card companies in the US _also_ make offers of no-fee balance transfers and I too get such offers by e-mail and by post (US Mail for US readers) but when I apply by phone or reply by e-mail, these offers promptly change to 2% or 3% transfer fee offers because I am presumably marked down as a known dead-beat who does his utmost to avoid paying credit-card interest.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I have taken out 3 or 4 of these offers over the years with different providers and there has been no transfer fee each time. I have had many other offers with no transfer fees either. The first time I heard about these balance transfer fees for customers in the USA was actually on this site. A bit better regulations on the banks here I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

No, because of the balance transfer fees, which could be 4%. Unless of course you get a deal for 12 months of no payment, and you pay it back in 12 months, in which case a 4% annual interest rate is much less than a loan! At that point you are gambling that you will be responsible with the payments, and the card company is taking the opposite bet.

Comment: Is he transferring anything or just charging with a zero rate offer?

Comment: If he's doing a balance transfer, there are cards that offer a balance transfer fee-free with no interest for x month in an effort to encourage you to switch to their company