# What is the catch with "balance transfer" credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, balance-transfer

If I understand correctly I can transfer a balance of my credit card to a new credit card and pay no interest for 40 months?

> **How your promotional rates will change**
>
> After 40 months, the rate on  Balance Transfers will go from 0% to 18.95%.
>
> After 6 months, the rateon Purchases will go from 0% to 18.95%.
>
> **Fees to be aware of**
>
> For a balance transfer, you'll be charged 2.39% of the balance you're
> transferring.

Of course I should be super-vigilant to repay the money within 40 months period but still... How do they make money?

Comment: They make money by getting you to switch to their card. This is a minor marketing cost. See past answers with the balance-transfer tag.

Comment: They are making 2.39% off the top. Unless you pay off the _entire_ balance (including the 0% part) before the 6-month period expires, you will be paying interest on purchases from day of purchase onwards till day of payoff (which will be much later than you think). Read _[this answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/63127/5760)_ to understand how balance transfer offers really work and why they are such a good deal for credit-card companies and a such a very had deal for consumers.

Answer (score 4):

They immediately make money by charging you the initial 2.39% fee.

In the long term they make money because a surprisingly large number of customers don't pay the balance off, or otherwise violate the terms of the offer, so that the 18.95% rate applies.

And sometimes, depending on card policies, they make money when the consumer makes new purchases on the card which accrue interest immediately at the 18.95% rate while payments only go to paying down the 0% rate balance.