# Is it possible to max out a credit card and then transfer balance to pay 0% interest for 40 months?

Tags: credit-card, balance-transfer

Last night I've asked a question - [What is the catch with "balance transfer" credit cards?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/71408/what-is-the-catch-with-balance-transfer-credit-cards) - but I wasn't precise enough...

Quite rightfully it was marked as duplicate and provided reference to two more great answers:

- [Why do credit card companies keep advertising balance transfers to those who don't carry a balance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/62975/why-do-credit-card-companies-keep-advertising-balance-transfers-to-those-who-don/63127#63127)
- https://money.stackexchange.com/a/25174/9663
- Also the tag: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balance-transfer

Now the question - is it possible to:

1. fully utilise existing credit card *(buy stuff aka speculative investment)*
2. transfer balance at 3% fee
3. then not pay any interest for 40 months

Of course I should be super-vigilant to fully pay off the card before the full interest kicks in. I should also keep minimal monthly repayments... Is there anything I need to know to make it real?

Answer (score 2):

Sure is it possible.

What does it give you? You basically get a '3% in 40 months' credit for 10 or 20 or 30 k$ (whatever your max is), that makes about 0.8%-0.9% per year. That's a relatively cheap credit, but that's all you get.
Your credit score will go down, because you'll have a pretty high ratio, and your other credit cards might go up in interest (which only matters *if* you carry a balance). If you want to buy a car or a house within these 40 months, you are paying an arm and a leg more on the loan/mortgage.

That doesn't seem like a good deal for me. Aside from the fact that if you don't pay back in time, it immediately becomes a nightmare credit card debt.

But if you think that is a good deal, go ahead and do it.

Comment: I get relatively cheap credit. *"other credit cards might go up in interest (which only matters if you carry a balance)"* - I don't get that... Say I spend £2k on AmEx and then transfer £2k to a new card. I'll continue using AmEx as usual and I'll defer repayments for 40 months... I don't think any interest changes will affect me - am I getting it right? ••• I have a car and I'm not sure if I want to buy a house - London real-estate prices are from outer space (so totally inflated by investors from Russia / Asia / Middle-East)...